# Big O - O(N^2) or O(N^2 + 1)?

Tags: algorithm, big-o

I'm reading [this](http://rob-bell.net/2009/06/a-beginners-guide-to-big-o-notation/) Big O article (and some other book references) trying to figure out what changes affect my algorithm.

so given the following O(N^2) code:

```
bool ContainsDuplicates(String[] strings)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < strings.Length; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < strings.Length; j++)
        {
            if(i == j) // Don't compare with self
            {
                continue;
            }

            if(strings[i] == strings[j])
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

I made the following change:

```
bool ContainsDuplicates(String[] strings)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < strings.Length; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < strings.Length; j++)
        {
            if(i != j) // Don't compare with self
            {                               

                   if(strings[i] == strings[j])
                   {
                      return true;
                   }
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Now both IF's are nested and 'continue' is removed. Does this algorithm really became a O(N^2 + 1) ? and why ? 
As far as I see the IF check was there before regardless, so initially thought it would still be a O(N^2).

Comment: In big-Oh notation, there's no such thing as `O(N^2 + 1)` because constants don't count (this is *asymptotic* complexity and **not** "identical" complexity).

Comment: which means their runtime and complexity are the same? both functions are O(N^2) ?

Comment: O(N²+1) is the same as O(N²) because N² *dominates* 1.

Comment: @H2CO3 `"there's no such thing as O(N^2 + 1)"` - actually I believe that that's not true - it's perfectly valid, although redundant, to include the `+1`.

Comment: @Dukeling Um, okay. I though that notation was for minimal asymptotic complexities, but I see where you're coming from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Big O is describing how execution time grows as a chosen parameter becomes large.

In your example, if we wanted to be exact, the formula would be:

> Time taken = Time(start) + Time(external loop) * N + Time (continue) * N + Time (no continue) * N^2

Which can be rewritten as

> Time taken = a + b * N + c * N^2

Now, as N becomes larger and larger, it's clear that overall this will be shaped like a parabola. The order zero and order one terms become irrelevant as N grows to infinity.

> Time taken (large N) ~= c * N^2

Finally, since we are interested in discussing *qualitatively* and not *quantitatively*, we simply describe the algorirhm as N^2

> O(N^2) means that the algorithm will behave approximately as c * N^2 for large values of N

It is a similar concept to o(x) in calculus (with the difference that small-o is for parameters going to zero.

Comment: ok! now I finally get it why only the larger N get considered! for it being qualitatively, so if my X axis got a +1 doesn't mean I added it to my runtime.

Comment: @Fawix keep in mind that the quantitative value depends on which computer you run the algorithm, whereas the O class is independent.